# Linux Mint - Deleted Bottom Panel - How To Un-Delete?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

So, being the explorer I am, I accidentally clicked the wrong thing.

The Panel at the bottom of the screen on Linux Mint using Cinnamon Desktop, I right clicked and selected either delete or remove (I can't remember).

Now it looks like I have a desktop with no panels on any screen. All I have is my desktop Icons, and CTRL+ALT+T to open term.

How can I "un-delete" the panel I just deleted?

Comment: (perhaps there needs to be an undo)

Answer (score 3):

You can't "undelete" a panel you deleted, but you can re-create it...

Press ALT-F2 and enter `cinnamon-settings`, then go to Panel and press the `Add new panel` button, select the location for the new panel and select the position (top or bottom) and you will get a new blank panel.

Once you get the panel, add applets to it and select "Restore to defaults" which should restore the panel to it's original settings and applets. If not, you will need to add the applets manually, in general you will want to add:

Menu (the "start" button)
Calendar
Keyboard
Network Manager
Notifications (will not appear unless active notifications)
Panel Launchers (Quick Launch shortcuts)
Power Manager
Removable Drives (will not appear if there is no drive connected)
Show Desktop
Sound (volume)
System Tray (will not appear unless there are active items)
Window List (the tabs for running apps)
Windows Quick List

And optionally:
Bluetooth
User Applet
Workspace Switcher

Note that adding them manually will not place them in the correct position, so you may need to move them around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Alt-F2] for run dialog. Run `cinnamon-settings`

Go to Panel, "Add new panel"

Answer (score 1):

This solution is taken from https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2195

1. Open up your terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Run the following command in the terminal:

   gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon (THIS IS FOR CINNAMON)

   gsettings reset-recursively org.mate.panel (THIS IS FOR MATE)
3. Hit Enter
4. Taraa!!! you should have your panel back to their default again.

Comment: *"Taraa!!!"* -- ??? Do you mean "ta-dah!" like a magician?

Comment: Although this will likely work, for Cinnamon it also resets a bunch of other Cinnamon settings to default, not just the panel. :/

Comment: and xfce? .......